# Change format of data (string to datetime)

Tags: google-bigquery

Hi I'm looking for function which i could change this type of data: '2022-01-01T00:00:00+00:00'
to: '2022-01-01 00:00:00' and in final must be in string format

Answer (score 1):

Consider below example

```
select format_timestamp('%F %T', timestamp '2022-01-01T00:00:00+00:00')
```

with output

[image]